# Extract multiple instances of Text from MySQL column bounded by some characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to extract certain snippets from a MySQL column which are bounded in some unique way. Here is an example:

I have the following table (TableA):

```
id | column_a
---+---------
1  | There is a user [u?u=990] and another [u?u=5458855].
2  | And here is just one user [u?u=9390].
3  | And here is nothing.
```

And I want to get this:

```
id | result_a
---+---------
1  | 990
1  | 5458855
2  | 9390
```

At the moment I have this query:

```
SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_a, '[u?u=', -1), ']', 1) AS result_a FROM TableA
```

But that gives me:

```
id | result_a
---+---------
1  | 5458855
2  | 9390
```

How can I improve this query?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the maximum number of such snippets in a single row already known to you?

Comment: No, it could be 0 or 10 for instance. Would it help to assume some high maximum that is unlikely to be reached? Then pick 100.
Thanks!

Comment: This is hard to do in SQL. You could do it in a Stored Procedure, but it would probably be much easier in a client language like PHP or Python.

Comment: It's similar to trying to do `explode()` in SQL, you can only do it if you limit the number of items in a row. WIth 100, you would have to repeat some code 100 times, because there are no loops in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has arisen because your schema violates [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

A normalised schema would contain another table (that looks rather like the result you're trying to obtain, perhaps with an additional "position" column that indicates from whence in the original source the value heralded), and the values in `column_a` within your existing table would then not contain the numbers you're after but rather some sort of placeholder instead.

Of course, this is (in a manner of speaking) what you're trying to construct…

SQL is really not very well suited to extracting multiple results from a single source row: the only way that can arise in MySQL is via a `JOIN`.  For example, one could attempt to obtain two instances from each row thusly—

```sql
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_a, '[u?u=', -1 - n.v)
           , ']', 1) AS result_a
FROM   TableA JOIN (
         SELECT 0 v
       UNION ALL
         SELECT 1
       ) n
```

Of course, this approach has a few problems:

1. It returns two records for *every* row, which is not correct—this could be resolved by filtering for only those where the found text matches the desired pattern:

   ```sql
   WHERE RIGHT(column_a, 5+CHAR_LENGTH(
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_a, '[u?u=', -1 - n.v)
         )) REGEXP '^\\[u\\?u=.*\\]'
   ```
2. It requires that the joined table counts all the way up to the maximum number of expected instances, which you've said could be as many as 100—rather than doing this explicitly, which is obviously cumbersome for such a large number, one can join multiple tables to achieve multiplication instead e.g. using binary (to 128 though a `WHERE` filter within table `n` could restrict to some smaller number if so desired):

   ```sql
   SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_a, '[u?u=', -1 - n.v)
              , ']', 1) AS result_a
   FROM   TableA JOIN (
            SELECT b6.v | b5.v | b4.v | b3.v | b2.v | b1.v | b0.v AS v
            FROM   (
                     SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0
                   ) b0 JOIN (
                     SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<1
                   ) b1 JOIN (
                     SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<2
                   ) b2 JOIN (
                     SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<3
                   ) b3 JOIN (
                     SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<4
                   ) b4 JOIN (
                     SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<5
                   ) b5 JOIN (
                     SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<6
                   ) b6
          ) n
   WHERE  RIGHT(column_a, 5+CHAR_LENGTH(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_a, '[u?u=', -1 - n.v)
          )) REGEXP '^\\[u\\?u=.*\\]'
   ```
3. MySQL's string functions are not particularly efficient, and this approach will be pretty slow.

Answer (score -1):

This is a weird way of handling a database. In the best practices you shouldn't have more than 1 information in 1 column.

In your case I would use REGEXP
[RegExp in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

I don't have MySQL so I can't write you an example but I think you can try it yourself.

Comment: As described in the article to which you have linked, MySQL's `REGEXP` operator returns a boolean result (i.e. whether the given string matches the given pattern)—it does not enable one to extract the substring(s) that match(es) the given pattern, and definitely does not enable one to extract multiple results per pattern.  -1

Comment: You're right,I deserve the -1... I mainly wanted to highlight the fact that's it's weird to store data this way and I can't comment on other posts...